# Simulating interpolation on Brownian motion with Julia

Tags: julia, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate a Brownian motion. The function does not return me an error but it seems like Julia does not put the value on vector B. Here the codes.

```
function interpolation(i,j,N,BM) 
       if j-i>1
       k = sqrt((j-i)/((2^N))/4)
       d = (i+j)/2
       BM[d] =((BM[i]+BM[j])/2)+k*randn(1)
       BM = interpolation(i,d,N,BM)
       BM = interpolation(d,j,N,BM)
       end
       end

plot(BM)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you also post the part of the code where you're assigning the initial value to `BM` and also how you're calling the `interpolation` method?

Comment: I'm pretty bad at understanding recursive functions, but one thing about this looks off. Usually a recursive function has >=1 conditional branches where you don't recursively call the function, a.k.a. the *base cases*. Your code only has 1 branch that does recursion, so the implicit base case is skipping the if-statement to the end of the function, which would return `nothing`. Maybe `nothing` is propagating through your recursive calls? This isn't a MWE, so we can't find out ourselves.

Comment: @BatWannaBe This is a pretty standard recursive way to generate a fractal. The idea is that the function side effects BM.

Comment: @Ted Dunning I see, so the bulk of the work is being done in the `BM[d]=...` line, and the recursive calls are looping back to it. In that case, I'm surprised there ISN'T an error, because the first recursive call reassigns `BM` to the base case `nothing` after mutating a `Vector`, so the second recursive call would attempt `BM=interpolation(d,j,N,nothing)`.

Comment: @BatWannaBe See my separate answer for the way to avoid the problems you are having. The key is that each recursive call has its own pointer to the array. My answer also uses `@view` so that the maintenance of which part of the array I am working on is handled by Julia itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code could be simplified by using array views. That eliminates all of the extra parameters from you code and makes it easier to see what it is doing. The normalization so that changes are smaller for interior steps could be simplified as well.

So here is a stab at this simplification:

```
function fractal(x) 
    if length(x) > 2
        n = length(x)
        mid = (n+1)÷2
        x[mid] = (x[1] + x[n])/2 + randn() * sqrt(n)
        fractal(@view x[1:mid])
        fractal(@view x[mid:n])
    end
end
```

And here is a result of this code running:

```
a = zeros(1024)
fractal(a)
plot(a, legend=false)
```

[image: Resulting plot of fractal]

The point of the simplification is to highlight the idea that the algorithm involves:

1. Interpolating the middle value based on the end-points
2. Do the same to the left and right halves of the array
3. if we don't have a big enough array, just return

This approach avoids complicating the picture with all of the housekeeping and it worked first try, largely because, I think, I didn't have to keep all that stuff straight.